# UTF-8 file encoding in R

Tags: r, utf-8, file-encodings

I have a `.csv` file which should be in 'UTF-8' encoding. I have exported it from Sql Server Management Studio. However, when importing it to `R` it fails on the lines with `ÿ`. I use read.csv2 and specify file encoding "UTF-8-BOM".

`Notepad++` correctly displays the `ÿ` and says it is UTF-8 encoding. Is this a bug with the `R` encoding, or is `ÿ` in fact not part of the UTF-8 encoding scheme?

I have uploaded a small `tab delimited` `.txt` file that fails here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2d5yj8sv299bsu/TestData.txt

Thanks

Comment: ÿ is code 255 for ISO 8859-1.  I suspect code has an EOF condition written to an 8-bit character.

Comment: In what way does R fail the importing? An error message of some sort or data gets cut off or transformed somehow?

Comment: @LauriK No error message - just cuts off the import at the first line containing the letter.

Comment: Seems like what @chux said could be true. So you can either use some other R functions or if it's a one-time deal then replace the character in Notepad++ with something else and replace it back in R.

Comment: Do you mean that the r code for `read.csv()` reads `ÿ` as EOF? I have tried using read.table and saving as tab delimited text files instead but I get the same problem. Do you have any suggestions for what function to use?

Answer (score 0):

That is probably part of the BOM marker at the beginning. If the editor or parser doesn't recognize BOM markers it believes it is garbage. See https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/unicode.html for more details.